# Ubuntu Server 22.04 with AD and File sharing

Tags: 22.04, samba, sharing

I need to setup an Ubuntu Server 22.04 for its own Active Directory with Folders and File Sharing to Clients which will be run on Ubuntu Desktop 22..
for that I configures 2 VMs on different hosts.

Server Guest IP is 10.10.10.71
client Guest IP is 10.10.10.72

Both Guest has same IP Pools. like my other clients runs on 10.10.10.0/24

Both VMs hosts can contact each other but guest cannot.
in Both VMS I set one Bridged connection and one NAT as read from forums.

Nother thing is I have configured my domain is prod.local on 10.10.10.71 IP.
samba ad is also running.

While installing client, Ubuntu cannot find my domain prod.local.
How to slove?

Please help.

Comment: I've done with networking in VMs. Now both guests on different hosts can ping each other.

Comment: Coming to main point. How to setup basic Fileserver with Active Directory(local) which have users and their sharing folders... All clients will have Ubuntu Desktop versions to login to AD or Local server and access shared files .